# Adding fragments to my main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Ok so,I'm new to Android programing and I have a question. I have a swipeview similar to the one in the Play Store,and I want each tab to contain a different listview fragment. I have 2 fragments ,one called LP and other PL ,lets say. How to I edit this part of code so it uses my fragments ?

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return fragment = new Fragment1();
    case 1:
        return fragment = new Fragment2();
    case 2:
        return fragment = new Fragment3();
    default:
        break;
    }
    return fragment;
```

EDIT : So after listening to the advice given,it still doesent work. :-?? I have 2 separate java files for my fragments and it doesent seem to work unless i copy the classes and put them inside the main activity...I may be missing something ,so please feel free to point out any posibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

switch (position) {
case 0:
 Fragment fragment = new Fragment1();
    return fragment;
case 1:
 Fragment fragment = new Fragment2();
    return fragment;
case 2:
 ListFragment fragment = new Fragment3();//for list fragments
    return fragment;
default:
    break;
}
return fragment;
```

Comment: Thank you. :) I will try to further improve my skills ,fragments are a bit confusing for a beginer :D

Comment: Well, they are pretty useful too. :)

Comment: @user3080155 You got to accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment result;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            result = new LPFragment();
        case 1:
            result = new PLFragment();
        default:
            result = new DefaultFragment();
    }

    return result
}
```

You just need to return an instance of whatever fragment you want for each case in the switch.

If the PL and LP classes extends from Fragment then it's fine (though you may have some need to cast them elsewhere in the code as the function returns Fragment and not your own class types)

Comment: One class extends Listfragment while the other extends Fragment.... How shoud i proceed?